# docker build command doesn't refresh my source files

Tags: docker

I made a typo in my source code and I noticed it after i run `docker-compose up` in my cli. I tried rebuilding the project but didn't change my `index.js` cached code.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app: 
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4001:8081"
```

I recreated the `image`

```
$ sudo docker build -t phillalexakis/visits:latest .
```

and run

```
docker-composer up
```

It didn't change the source code at all, what have I completely missed? (I'm new with docker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker-compose is looking for an image named `[folder_name]_node-app`, but the image you've built is tagged `phillalexakis/visits`.

Change your node-app service in `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
  node-app: 
    build: .
    image: node-app
```

And use docker-compose to build the images:

`docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: `docker-compose up --build` did the job thank you!